# Unable to establish WiFi connection between client and server in qt

Tags: qt

I'm developing an app to connect 2 devices (one as server, the other as client)so they can communicate with each other (i.e send from one of them and receive in the other one). These 2 devices are connected to the same WiFi. For test (on 2 windows laptops) I've made an installer file from the client code, installed and run it on the second device. But the communication is not established. Where is the problem?

Is there any setting that I have to do?

Note: I've run the app (both server and client) on my laptop and it worked. But for 2 laptops it didn't!

Here is my server.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    _server = new QTcpServer(this);

    _server->listen(QHostAddress::Any,2000);
    statusBar()-> showMessage("listening...");
   connect(_server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(newConnection()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::newConnection()
{
  _socket =
        _server->nextPendingConnection();
  connect(_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead())
          ,this ,SLOT(readData()));
  ui->label->setText("connection stablished");
  statusBar()->showMessage("");


}
void MainWindow::readData()
{
  QByteArray ba = _socket->readAll();
  QString str(ba);
  ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(str);

}
```

and the client.cpp:

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QHostAddress>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->progressBar->hide();
    _socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(_socket,SIGNAL(connected())
            ,this,SLOT(connectToHost()));


}

//127.0.0.1 == localhost
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::connectToHost()
{
    ui->progressBar->hide();
    ui->btn_send->setEnabled(true );

}

void MainWindow::on_btn_connect_clicked()
{
    ui->progressBar->show();
     QHostAddress address("127.0.0.1");
    _socket -> connectToHost(address,2000);//inja darkhast connection ersal mishe.

}

void MainWindow::on_btn_send_clicked()
{

    QByteArray  data = ui->LED_send_text
            ->text().toLocal8Bit();
    _socket->write(data );
}
```

Comment: What are your firewall settings?  Port 2000 is probably blocked by default.

Comment: This is not about Qt. And you need to realize what you do first. There is no WiFi involved in your code but localhost which is internal to the PC. As for the question "connect to the same WiFi" the closest comes HotSpot WiFi mode which actually means your PC acting as WiFi router for others. If you talk about multi-channel WiFi with bidirectional capabilities like STA to STA (station to station) it is available in 802.11 WiFi spec but not implemented in any of actual drivers (I was looking for that).

Comment: Perhaps you should first find out what your server's IP address is. You need to connect to that instead of 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback address on your client. I strongly suggest reading up on networking basics before continuing with your project

Comment: @G.M. tnx for reply. But I've tested the app through LAN and for other ports and it worked. So I think it is not about port 2000.

Comment: @ AlexanderVX tnx. Could you please explain it more obvious? How should I fix it for "There is no WiFi involved in your code but localhost" ?

Comment: @RobbieE Yeeeeaaaahh you're right and finally it worked. Thanks to all for help ;)